# Logistic regression using customer survey data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression

I have a project which I'm not sure how to implement. I need to build a logistic regression using customer survey data to predict NPS (actually, the coefficients are more important for this use case).

I feel confident using various machine learning data sets, but I have several concerns about customer survey data. My questions are:

1. Scales encoding. Example question: "How long did you have to wait? a) less than 10 mins, b) 10-20 mins, c) 20-30 mins, d) more than 30 mins". This is interval data, so I can leave the values as 1, 2, 3 and 4, right? Also satisfaction scales are really common - from very satisfied to very dissatisfied.
2. "Don't know" option in questions like "Do you agree XYZ?: a) yes, b) no, c) don't know ". Do I simply remove those, since it conveys no useful information to the algorithm?
3. P-values and dummy variables. Since a lot of questions are nominal, I have to use pd.get_dummies(). But when I fit statsmodels' Logit() model, I see that a lot of variables have p value of 1. How do I proceed in this case?

Thanks in advance, I hope my questions make sense.

Edit: NPS in this case means 1 if Promoter (values 9 and 10) and 0 if anything else.

Answer (score 0):

1. if it is scalar and keep the relation of "greathear than" you can encode 
   [10,20];[20:30] ... to 1,2 ... if they don't have this relationship, like: "do you like blue or red?", then you should use one hot encoding.
2. use one hot encoding like

```
yes =        [1,0,0]
no =         [0,1,0]
dont_know =  [0,0,1]
```

3. Seems you have a problem of multi-collinearity, you should regularize data, drop the variable or use other models in order to avoid it. Another thing that maybe is causing it is that your x and y are the same thing or you are not considering TIME, e.g: you use recency (last time of use) for a churn model as your x, but you define churn as recency> n-days.